# Best way to store Zip Code for user session - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cookies, session-cookies, zipcode

I have a site that calculates shipping costs, but I need the user to input zip code.  I have considered GeoKit for my RoR site, but my question is - how do I store the zip code as a session variable?

Is a cookie the best way to do this? The user does not have to be logged in to enter zip code.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would store it on the session itself, which typically is backed by a cookie.  You can do it from the controller as simple as this:

```
session[:zip_code] = '12345'
```

See here for more information on the Rails session: http://rails.nuvvo.com/lesson/6372-action-controller-session